# Strange Menu Behaviour

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Unfortunately I have a strange menu behavior on my website http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/. The toggle function in my menu actually works. As you can see the menu items fold out when you click on them. So far so good. Now when I click on a menu item, for example "MiniLine-2 System", all menu items suddenly fold out. I guess it's because of the jQuery code. Unfortunately I don't know that much about it. Can someone kindly help me?

```
 $('#navi-downloads .menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
            });
```

[image]

```js
 $('#navi-downloads .menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
                    
                    
                });
```

```html
<div class="menu-downloads-menu-de-container"><ul id="navi-downloads" class="list-group"><li id="menu-item-11849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11849"><a href="#">Datenblätter</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-12018" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-12018"><a href="#">NauticProfil®</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-11850" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11850"><a href="#">NauticProfil® Leuchteneinsätze</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-11851" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11851"><a href="#">Leuchteneinsätze 24V</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-9147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9147"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-sta-maria-4/">NP Line Sta. Maria-4</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10840" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10840"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-victory-6/">NP Line Victory-6</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9142"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-navigator/">NP Line Navigator</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9146"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-radiant/">NP Line Radiant</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9143"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-nova-4/">NP Line Nova-4</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9144"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-pegasus-3/">NP Line Pegasus-3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9145"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-pegasus-3-gold/">NP Line Pegasus-3 Gold</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10841" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10841"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-discovery-2/">NP Line Discovery-2</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
            <li id="menu-item-11852" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11852"><a href="#">Leuchteneinsätze 48V</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-10838" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10838"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-sta-maria-5/">NP Line Sta. Maria-5</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10835" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10835"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-navigator-2/">NP Line Navigator-2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10836" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10836"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-nova-5/">NP Line Nova-5</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10839" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10839"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-sunfelipe/">NP Line SunFelipe</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
            <li id="menu-item-10842" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10842"><a href="#">Focus-3 Leuchteneinsätze</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-10846" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10846"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-1ch/">NP Focus-3 1CH</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10845" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10845"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-1ch-darklite/">NP Focus-3 1CH Darklite</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10844" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10844"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-4ch/">NP Focus-3 4CH</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10843" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10843"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-4ch-darklite/">NP Focus-3 4CH Darklite</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-9155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9155"><a href="#">NauticProfil® Montageprofile</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-9150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9150"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-s1/">NauticProfil®  S1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10833" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10833"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-s2/">NauticProfil®  S2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10824" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10824"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-s3/">NauticProfil® S3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9137"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-h1/">NauticProfil®  H1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9138"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-h2/">NauticProfil®  H2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10825" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10825"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-h3/">NauticProfil® H3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10826" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10826"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-r1/">NauticProfil®  R1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10829" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10829"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-r2/">NauticProfil® R2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10828" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10828"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-r3/">NauticProfil® R3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9139"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-i1/">NauticProfil® I1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9140"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-i2/">NauticProfil® I2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10830" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10830"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-w1/">NauticProfil® W1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10831" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10831"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-w2/">NauticProfil® W2</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-12078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-12078"><a href="#">NauticNanoProfil</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-12080" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12080"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/nauticnanoprofil/">NauticNanoProfil</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12079"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/nauticnanoprofil-horizon/">NauticNanoProfil Horizon</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-10834" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10834"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/h2flex/">H2flex Systembaukasten</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9136"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/miniline-2-system-2/">MiniLine-2 System</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9153"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/solaris-2/">Solaris-2 4Channel</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10850" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10850"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/picospot/">PicoSpot³</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10849"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/oligo-adapt-2/">OLIGO Adapt-2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11993" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11993"><a href="#">Installationshinweise</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10852" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10852"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/verdrahtungsschemata/">Verdrahtungsschemata</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-11859" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11859"><a href="#">Planungshilfen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-10855" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10855"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/cad-dateien/">CAD Dateien</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-11992" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11992"><a href="#">Eulumdats-IES-LDT</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-12064" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12064"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-np-line-24v/">LVK NP Line 24V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12063" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12063"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-np-line-48v/">LVK NP Line 48V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12062" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12062"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-np-focus-3/">LVK NP Focus-3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12061" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12061"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-picospot%c2%b3/">LVK PicoSpot³</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12060" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12060"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-nnp-leuchteneinsaetze-24v/">LVK NNP Leuchteneinsätze 24V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12059" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12059"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-solaris-2/">LVK Solaris-2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-11991" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11991"><a href="#">Excel-Konfigurator</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9134" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9134"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/formulare/">Formulare</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-11990" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11990"><a href="#">Ausschreibungstexte</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-12075" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12075"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/ausschreibungstexte-linearleuchten-24v/">Ausschreibungstexte Linearleuchten 24V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12074" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12074"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/ausschreibungstexte-linearleuchten-48v/">Ausschreibungstexte Linearleuchten 48V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12073" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12073"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/ausschreibungstexte-focus-3/">Ausschreibungstexte Focus-3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11857" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11857"><a href="#">Publikationen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-11856" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11856"><a href="https://flashaar.de/pdf/FLASHAAR_catalogue_2020.pdf">Katalog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9131"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/broschuren/">Broschüren</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9154"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/zertifikate/">Zertifikate</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9135"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/konformitatserklarung/">Konformitätserklärung</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11853" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11853"><a href="#">Geschäftsbedingungen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-9132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9132"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/datenschutz/">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9130"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/agb/">AGB</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9133"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/einkaufsbedingungen/">Einkaufsbedingungen</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you describe on your site. When clicking 'MimiLine-2 System' the menu does not change - nothing folds in or out. All that does happen is a redirect to eh new page. This is in Chrome 84 on Win10

Comment: I also can't see this behavior!? it's working normally. there might be something else integrating with your browsing, maybe a plugin or script that is working only for logged users? or for admins? also, can you try this in the incognito mode in chrome or your browser private session?

Comment: I have already tried it on different computers and systems, it is the same everywhere. When I click on the entry "MiniLine-2" the menu items "NauticProfil" and "NauticNanoProfil" and its submenus open at the same time. This should not happen, but I don't know how I can prevent this

Comment: Can you add a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question? As well as helping us to help you, it also makes the question meet the site guidelines - questions should be self-contained and include all the relevant information. External links can break or change over time and make the question invalid and unhelpful to future users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is due to the selector

#navi-downloads .menu-item-has-children > a

means

Select all `<a>` elements where the parent's class is .menu-item-has-children and is a descendant of #navi-downloads

Try to see if "NauticProfil" and "NauticNanoProfil" fulfill these conditions.

Also same comment as the other two, I did not see that kind of behavior when I tried it in my pc.

Comment: It's funny how no one here can see the mistake. But I think it has something to do with the selector. If I change the script to "#navi-downloads .menu-item-has-children a" the toggle mode works fine, but no more pages can be opened. With "#navi-downloads .menu-item-has-children > a" the following probably happens: when I click on a menu item that contains an a-tag, all menu items are expanded. Slowly I'm getting closer to it.

Comment: @Peter we can't see the mistake because you haven't shown us all of the relevant code! As I said above, questions need to include all the relevant code - as well as being a requirement using the site, it also means we don't have to click on links to unknown potentially malicious destinations to work out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the jquery code and now the menu behaves almost as desired. Unfortunately the page always jumps to the top when I click on a menu item. I would like to avoid this because it has an unfavourable effect especially on the lower menu items, because the visitor has to scroll down again and again. Does anyone have an idea?

```
$('#navi-downloads > li ul')
    .click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
    })
    .filter(':not(:first)')
    .hide();
    
  $('#navi-downloads > li, #navi-downloads > li > ul > li, #navi-downloads > li > ul > li >ul >li, #navi-downloads > li > ul > li >ul > li > ul > li').click(function(){
    var selfClick = $(this).find('ul:first').is(':visible');
    if(!selfClick) {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .find('> li ul:visible')
        .slideToggle();
    }
    
    $(this)
      .find('ul:first')
      .stop(true, true)
      .slideToggle();
  });
```

```js
 $('#navi-downloads .menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
                    
                    
                });
```

```html
<div class="menu-downloads-menu-de-container"><ul id="navi-downloads" class="list-group"><li id="menu-item-11849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11849"><a href="#">Datenblätter</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-12018" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-12018"><a href="#">NauticProfil®</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-11850" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11850"><a href="#">NauticProfil® Leuchteneinsätze</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-11851" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11851"><a href="#">Leuchteneinsätze 24V</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-9147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9147"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-sta-maria-4/">NP Line Sta. Maria-4</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10840" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10840"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-victory-6/">NP Line Victory-6</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9142" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9142"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-navigator/">NP Line Navigator</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9146"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-radiant/">NP Line Radiant</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9143"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-nova-4/">NP Line Nova-4</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9144"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-pegasus-3/">NP Line Pegasus-3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-9145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9145"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-pegasus-3-gold/">NP Line Pegasus-3 Gold</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10841" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10841"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-discovery-2/">NP Line Discovery-2</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
            <li id="menu-item-11852" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11852"><a href="#">Leuchteneinsätze 48V</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-10838" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10838"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-sta-maria-5/">NP Line Sta. Maria-5</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10835" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10835"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-navigator-2/">NP Line Navigator-2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10836" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10836"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-nova-5/">NP Line Nova-5</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10839" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10839"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-line-sunfelipe/">NP Line SunFelipe</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
            <li id="menu-item-10842" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-10842"><a href="#">Focus-3 Leuchteneinsätze</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-10846" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10846"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-1ch/">NP Focus-3 1CH</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10845" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10845"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-1ch-darklite/">NP Focus-3 1CH Darklite</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10844" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10844"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-4ch/">NP Focus-3 4CH</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-10843" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10843"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-focus-3-4ch-darklite/">NP Focus-3 4CH Darklite</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="menu-item-9155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9155"><a href="#">NauticProfil® Montageprofile</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-9150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9150"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-s1/">NauticProfil®  S1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10833" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10833"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-s2/">NauticProfil®  S2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10824" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10824"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-s3/">NauticProfil® S3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9137"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-h1/">NauticProfil®  H1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9138"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-h2/">NauticProfil®  H2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10825" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10825"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-h3/">NauticProfil® H3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10826" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10826"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-r1/">NauticProfil®  R1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10829" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10829"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-r2/">NauticProfil® R2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10828" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10828"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-r3/">NauticProfil® R3</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9139"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-i1/">NauticProfil® I1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-9140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9140"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-i2/">NauticProfil® I2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10830" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10830"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-w1/">NauticProfil® W1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-10831" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10831"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/np-w2/">NauticProfil® W2</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-12078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-12078"><a href="#">NauticNanoProfil</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-12080" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12080"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/nauticnanoprofil/">NauticNanoProfil</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12079"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/nauticnanoprofil-horizon/">NauticNanoProfil Horizon</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-10834" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10834"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/h2flex/">H2flex Systembaukasten</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9136"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/miniline-2-system-2/">MiniLine-2 System</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9153" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9153"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/solaris-2/">Solaris-2 4Channel</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10850" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10850"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/picospot/">PicoSpot³</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-10849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10849"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/oligo-adapt-2/">OLIGO Adapt-2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11993" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11993"><a href="#">Installationshinweise</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10852" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10852"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/verdrahtungsschemata/">Verdrahtungsschemata</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-11859" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11859"><a href="#">Planungshilfen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-10855" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-10855"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/cad-dateien/">CAD Dateien</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-11992" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11992"><a href="#">Eulumdats-IES-LDT</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-12064" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12064"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-np-line-24v/">LVK NP Line 24V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12063" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12063"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-np-line-48v/">LVK NP Line 48V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12062" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12062"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-np-focus-3/">LVK NP Focus-3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12061" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12061"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-picospot%c2%b3/">LVK PicoSpot³</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12060" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12060"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-nnp-leuchteneinsaetze-24v/">LVK NNP Leuchteneinsätze 24V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12059" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12059"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/lvk-solaris-2/">LVK Solaris-2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-11991" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11991"><a href="#">Excel-Konfigurator</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9134" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9134"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/formulare/">Formulare</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-11990" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11990"><a href="#">Ausschreibungstexte</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-12075" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12075"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/ausschreibungstexte-linearleuchten-24v/">Ausschreibungstexte Linearleuchten 24V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12074" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12074"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/ausschreibungstexte-linearleuchten-48v/">Ausschreibungstexte Linearleuchten 48V</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12073" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-12073"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/ausschreibungstexte-focus-3/">Ausschreibungstexte Focus-3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11857" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11857"><a href="#">Publikationen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-11856" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11856"><a href="https://flashaar.de/pdf/FLASHAAR_catalogue_2020.pdf">Katalog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9131"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/broschuren/">Broschüren</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9154"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/zertifikate/">Zertifikate</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9135"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/konformitatserklarung/">Konformitätserklärung</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-11853" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-11853"><a href="#">Geschäftsbedingungen</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-9132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9132"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/datenschutz/">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9130"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/agb/">AGB</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-9133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-downloads menu-item-9133"><a href="http://www.pm-werbeagentur.de/downloads/einkaufsbedingungen/">Einkaufsbedingungen</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```